# List all comments and get the username of the author of another table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm adding a feedback system to a system of students, the idea is that teachers have access to a list of students and can leave a comment about that student.

Table masters:

```
id
username
```

Table comments:

```
id
id_master
id_student
text
```

Then I go to `student.php?id=1` show all results in table `comments`:

```
<?php
// See comments student
function SeeComments($id) { 
 $db = DB::getInstance();
 $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id_student = ?", array($id));
 $results = $query->results();
 return ($results);
}

$id = $_GET['id'];
$Data = SeeComments($id);

foreach ($Data as $v1) {
 echo "<b>Username - Text</b><br>";
 echo $v1->id_master." - ".$v1->text."<br>";
 echo "---------------------<br>";
}
?>
```

As I can get the `username` of the table `masters` to display the results instead of the `id` like:

```
echo $v1->username." - ".$v1->text."<br>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an inner join to get the related data from the `masters` table.

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT comments.*, masters.username 
    FROM comments 
    INNER JOIN masters ON comments.id_master = masters.id 
    WHERE comments.id_student = ?", array($id));
```

Now you should be able to get the username with: `$v1->username`.

You can read more about inner join's here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just what I wanted! Problem solved.